# Paid video platform vs HTML5

Tags: html, video

My company's website embeds videos, currently hosted on youtube. But due to the fact that as of recently, youtube inserts a channel icon into the embed, I will be moving the videos to either another platform, or will use HTML5 video.

I'm not crazy about one aspect or another of various platforms, except a very expensive one (Wistia).

So I'm looking into HTML5, and have a couple of questions. First, in almost 2019, would I still need multiple formats? The audience is non-technical, largely upscale, and would likely be using Chrome, IE, Firefox, Sarafi or Edge.

This has been asked before, but nowadays do you think I'm safe using only MP4? And if so, any thoughts about ongoing browser support for H.264?

Thanks! Steve

Comment: MP4 is a solid choice (you'll want to optimize encoding for streaming) and will hit a large %age of modern browsers, though you may want to also serve .webm or .ogv version as a fallback. You could also look at encoding HLS or Dash and use something like video.js or shaka for playback. You could track stats against the `canPlayType` method to validate need for alternatives. Does your current audience stats show that HTML5 capable browsers are supported by a high enough percentage (fairly safe bet, except for some countries/demographics. FWIW I consult on this so feel free to ping, link in bio

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5.

`<video>` tag is supported in all major browsers and it looks like MP4 is supported as well. [(check it out here)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)